# Retrieving value from Database to use on welcome screen

Tags: html, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got this website project and when the user logs in using their email address, the website welcomes them.

[Example] http://gyazo.com/4789acfb6714a8be1bffc479b81af74f

[HTML Code with Razor Syntax]

```
<div style="width:auto;">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <strong>Hello, @Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
        @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOut", "MyTemplate")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Registration", "MyTemplate")
        <span>|</span>
        @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "LogIn", "MyTemplate")
    }
</div>
```

However, during the signup process, the users are required to input a FirstName.

How do I retrieve this FirstName from the database I currently have? So instead of displaying "admin@admin.com" it would say "admin".

[Database] http://gyazo.com/fc01763a97470c3ddf2e2e50f9f379a3

I know that line 4 (`<strong>Hello, @Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>`)is responsible for getting the user's email address however I don't know how to retrieve the user's FirstName.

EDIT:
Relevant project files: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb481f973a7fa5840023

The tutorial I followed and the basic template I looked at from Visual Studio 2013 simply used @Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name) or User.Identity.Name to display the email section/ the name of the user. I have no idea how it works :\

Answer (score 0):

You basically do:

```
var name = new MyMainDBEntities().SystemUsers.First(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name).Name;
```

Granted, this is the quick and dirty way to do it. You still need to `Dispose` of the database and do it inside the controller. What you are doing right now is breaking concerns across UI and back-end data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Where would one place this code? In the _layout.cshtml? or is this part of the controller somewhere?